# How to prove $ \sum_{k=1}^{p+1} \binom{p+1}{k}S_{n}^{p+1-k} = (n+1)^{p+1}-1$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, summation, binomial-theorem

This is the solution $ \sum_{k=1}^{p+1} \binom{p+1}{k}S_{n}^{p+1-k} =  \sum_{k=1}^{p+1} \binom{p+1}{k} \sum_{l=1}^{n}l^{p+1-k} = \sum_{l=1}^{n}(l+1)^{p+1}-l^{p+1} = (n+1)^{p+1}-1$ ?

With $S_{n}^{p} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^p$.

Comment: What is $\ell$ in the middle summation?

Comment: $ l = S_n = n^p?$ @BrianM.Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse the order of summation and apply the binomial theorem:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{p+1}\binom{p+1}k\sum_{\ell=1}^n\ell^{p+1-k}&=\sum_{\ell=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^{p+1}\binom{p+1}k\ell^{p+1-k}\\\\
&=\sum_{\ell=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^{p+1}\binom{p+1}k1^k\ell^{p+1-k}\\\\
&=\sum_{\ell=1}^n\left(\sum_{k=0}^{p+1}\binom{p+1}k1^k\ell^{p+1-k}-\binom{p+1}01^0\ell^{p+1}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{\ell=1}^n\left((\ell+1)^{p+1}-\ell^{p+1}\right)\\\\
&=(n+1)^{p+1}-1\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I don't understand this passage: $ \sum_{\ell=1}^n\left(\sum_{k=0}^{p+1}\binom{p+1}k1^k\ell^{p+1-k}-\binom{p+1}01^0\ell^{p+1}\right)\\\\
=\sum_{\ell=1}^n\left((\ell+1)^{p+1}-\ell^{p+1}\right)\\\\$

Comment: @CAFosta: $(1+\ell)^{p+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{p+1}\binom{p+1}k1^k\ell^{p+1-k}$ by the binomial theorem, and $\binom{p+1}01^0\ell^{p+1}=\ell^{p+1}$ by direct calculation.